# How can I generate a password-less version of a protected PDF?

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a PDF file that has been password protected.  I know the password.  The password's only use, in our case, is to protect the PDF during email transmission.  Now that I have the PDF, I'd like to remove the password, as it is annoying to have to look-up and type it in every time I want to use the PDF.

In a pre-Lion version of Preview, I was able to print and "Save As PDF" to create a copy of the file that didn't have a password.  However, when I try the same maneuver in Lion, the "Save as PDF" entry is greyed-out.

Is there some other software (preferably free) that would let me save the PDF without the password?  Some other thing I can do to the file to enable Preview to "Save as PDF"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Open the document in Preview, select File > Duplicate, enter the file location and save a copy.

You can do a similar thing with File > Export.

Comment: It keeps asking me for password saying "Without the owner password, you do not have permission to duplicate this document". I am on Mountain Lion, btw.

Comment: Does not work for me. A workaround that actually works :  Open the PDF in Chrome (or Firefox) and then Print it to PDF as destination.

Comment: @NitishUpreti for the love of god add that as an answer. That totally worked for me. I used Chrome btw.

Answer (score 9):

Workaround (Working for most people) : Open the PDF in Chrome (or Firefox) and then Print it to PDF as destination.

Answer (score 1):

try "print to file" option :-)

Answer (score 1):

Open in Preview but instead of trying to create a duplicate or export it (which will also result in a locked PDF), just select `print / PDF`.