# Preview and PDF: Remove a password which I do know

Tags: pdf, preview

I have a protected PDF file, in which I cannot highlight text using Preview and which I cannot print without a password.

> [image]

I do know a password, but I cannot understand how to remove it from the document. I can click **File** > **Enter Password** and then **Unlock as Owner**, but the next time I open the document, it will be required to type the password again. How to do this?

> [image]

Just in case, I know about options like using `qpdf`, but since I do know the password, I would prefer to not use third-party tools.

Comment: Have you tried Saving, or Saving As, after you've Unlocked?

Comment: @benwiggy Yes, I have tried this.

Comment: Also: are the permissions reset when you've unlocked, or are they just no longer greyed out? You might have to explicitly change them.

Comment: @benwiggy If you mean permissions that are shown on the second screenshot, they are all become "green".

Comment: You can't remove a PDF password by just unlocking the file (see https://www.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/unlock-pdf.html). Not sure whether Preview can do it at all.

Comment: @nohillside Thanks. This is really what-the-heck. Since there is already an option to unlock the document for the current "session" (that is, until I close the document and then open it the next time), why the heck to not provide us an option to simply remove the password at all (?)

Comment: Apple actually recommends to create a copy if you want to keep the unprotected version (https://support.apple.com/guide/preview/password-protect-a-pdf-prvw587dd90f/mac, "Set a password", step 2). I agree that this seems strange, but there may be a technical reason for this.

Comment: https://ajoysoft.com/blogs/how-to-unlock-a-pdf-in-preview/ is one of the usual "click-bait to sell a product" pages, but did you try the steps in the first part?

Comment: Also, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/42222/how-can-i-generate-a-password-less-version-of-a-protected-pdf?rq=1 seems to be duplicate.

Comment: @AVelj That may work, but you will lose non-printing metadata like annotations, table of contents, etc.

Comment: Yes, this works, but to make exported version to look the same as the original document you need to know not only the paper size of the original document but also its margins. Seems to be a quick-and-dirty solution only.

Comment: Preview.app is not a PDF creation application, and for removing passwords, you need something like that. Well, if you do serious work with PDF, you won't be able to do it without Acrobat…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From a quick test, I can **Export...** from Preview to a new document, and use the Permissions dialog in the file save panel to enable all the permissions.

[image]

However, the Owner Password is still "there". But I can at least print, modify, and annotate the document without need to enter it.

Preview has been a poor flagship for the capabilities of PDFKit these last 25 years or so. It does look like something changed in Monterey that stopped just re-saving it from working.

I've also tried to remove the password programmatically (or even change it to the empty string), but so far without success.

You should be able to Save As a PDF from the Print dialog, but this will have the effect of losing any non-printing data, like Annotations, Table of Contents, etc.

Your best bet is probably a better PDF editing app.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem on macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 with Preview 11.0.

I've tried to *Export* a PDF that requires a password to open. Once entered, Preview perplexingly does not show a password in the export dialog (see below), yet the resulting PDF is again password protected. That makes no sense.

[image]

What worked for me was to **print** the unlocked PDF (File menu, Print). There was no mention there of a password in Security Options and the saved PDF was no longer password protected.

[image]

Preview also crashed once in the process. I did like the ease of use of Preview so far but this latest version is buggy and unconvincing.